# Bootstrap radio buttons wil not fire in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

My radio buttons work normally in Internet Explorer, but in Google Chrome the button don't seem to fire the div.alert_text nor div.question event. So am I missing something in the web kit, or does chrome hit the parent div? I set a debugger and hit it when I run IE, but when I run it in chrome nothing happens, there are bootstrap radio buttons, I put a debugger here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.alert_text").hide();

    $("div.question").find(':radio').click(function () {
        var isValid = $(this).hasClass('True');
        var divAlert = $(this).parents('.question').find('div.alert_text');
        debugger 
        if (!isValid) {
            divAlert.show();
            $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.btn').removeClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-danger');
            $(this).parents('.btn').addClass('btn-danger');
        }
        else {
            divAlert.hide();
            $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.btn').removeClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-danger');
            $(this).parents('.btn').addClass('btn-success');
        }

        // Enable-Disable Next Button
        if ($(":radio:checked.True").length == @Model.Count()) {
            $("#next").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("k-state-disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("#next").prop("checked", true).addClass("k-state-disabled");
        }
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            var id = item.QuestionID.ToString();
            var isYesValidAnswer = item.IsYesValidAnswer.Value ? "True" : "False";
            var isNoValidAnswer = item.IsNoValidAnswer.Value ? "True" : "False";
            <div class="row" style="background-color:darkgray; height:1px"></div>
            <div class="question row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="row"><b>@item.Title</b></div>
                    <div class="row">@item.Question</div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-11"><font size="2">@item.YesText</font></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-11"><font size="2">@item.NoText</font></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row alert_text">
                        <div class="col-md-12 k-widget k-notification k-notification-error">Alert! @item.AlertMessage</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="anwser col-md-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label for="" class="btn btn-default">
                        <input name="yes_no@(id)" class="@(isYesValidAnswer)" id="yes_no@(id)_True" value="True" type="radio">Yes
                    </label>
                    <label for="" class="btn btn-default">
                        <input name="yes_no@(id)" class="@(isNoValidAnswer)" id="yes_no@(id)_False" value="False" type="radio">No
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: The HTML would be useful to see this in context

Comment: You know when something works in IE and not Chrome that there's a serious problem

Comment: Jsfiddle please

Comment: @user1428716 There's no need for a jsfiddle when the code can be embedded in a snippet within the question.

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve


  [1]:

Comment: While, try deleting the browser cache in Chrome, or try in iconginto mode

Comment: Here is the HTML:

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle in which I've tried to cut down the html and js to only what we need to test this: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/49828/       Do you get a debugger here? You may need to have the console open

Comment: The answer or solution was to base the find one level up on the class btn and not the type radio.